# WPF smooth transition for databound property updates

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, mvvm

I have a control that has its margin bound to a property of my view model:

```
<Grid Margin="{Binding Path=Property1, Converter={StaticResource Converter1}}"></Grid>
```

How do I get a smooth animation between successive updates to the Margin property? I want the margin to slide for a short amount of time instead of a discrete jump. Preferably a xaml solution.

Edit:
This is different than the other questions on this site, because I would need the "From" in a thickness animation to be bound to the previous value, and "To" to be bound to the updated value. It seems like a hack to just add another property to the view model for this.

Comment: use a `ThicknessAnimation`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542657/how-to-animate-margin-property-in-wpf

Comment: @HighCore Is it possible to do a ThicknessAnimation without knowing the thickness? The possible values that my Margin is bound to cannot be determined before runtime.

Comment: @HerbertVonKarajan it's possible to use `{Binding XXX}` in the `From` and `To` properties, or the `Value` property for a KeyFrame, provided that your animation is  NOT defined inside a `DataTemplate` because it won't work that way.

Comment: @HighCore When the data updates, the new value will be set to "To", but how do you go about capturing the previous value for the "From"?

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution; the animation only needs to bind to the "From" and it will animate the way I want.

```
<Grid Margin="{Binding Path=Property1, 
        NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, 
        Converter={StaticResource Converter1}}">
    <Grid.Triggers><EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
        <BeginStoryboard><StoryBoard>
            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                Duration="00:00:00.5"
                                From="{Binding Path="Property1" Converter={StaticResource Converter1}}"/>
        </StoryBoard></BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger></Grid.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ThicknessAnimation`:

```
<BeginStoryboard>
    <Storyboard>    
      <!-- BorderThickness animates from left=1, right=1, top=1, and bottom=1 to
      left=28, right=28, top=14, and bottom=14 over one second. -->
      <ThicknessAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
        Duration="0:0:1.5" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" From="1,1,1,1" To="28,14,28,14" />
    </Storyboard>
  </BeginStoryboard>
```

You just need to bind the properties `From` and `To`

Comment: Is there any way to bind the "From" to the old value on update without adding another property to the view model?

Comment: Did u try  AutoReverse="True"