# Translate the grid to bottom of page

Tags: xaml, uwp-xaml

I want to be able to translate a grid to the bottom of page when a button is clicked. Currently I am using TranslateTransform to achieve that but the problem is that I have to give an integer value to which I have to translate the grid which would change when the height of container changes. My Storyboard:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="LowerChamberSlideDown">
     <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderTrans" 
                      BeginTime="0:0:1"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y"
                      To="288"
                      Duration="0:0:2"/>
</Storyboard>
```

My Grid:

```
        <Grid x:Name="LowerChamberHeader" 
              Grid.Row="0"
              VerticalAlignment="Top">


            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="HeaderTrans" Y="0"></TranslateTransform>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>

            <TextBlock Text="Lower Chamber" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       Margin="15,0,0,0" 
                       Foreground="White"/>
            <Button Height="20" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                    Margin="0,0,10,0">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/bmpExpandCollapse.bmp" 
                                Stretch="Uniform"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/bmpBlueImage.bmp"/>
            </Grid.Background>
        </Grid>
```

Is there a way to use VerticalAlignment property in animation and set it to bottom to translate the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution that also shows the nice transition of grid to the bottom of screen so I solved this issue by determining the height of the screen on `OnSizeChanged` event and then recalculating the `LowerChamberSlideDown.To` property from code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Got this answer from following link:
[How to animate Margin property in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542657/how-to-animate-margin-property-in-wpf)

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GroupTileSecond" 
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="HorizontalAlignment">

    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            <HorizontalAlignment>Center</HorizontalAlignment>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Thanks,

Jessie