# c#(UWP) - changing top margin with doubleanimation

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-store-apps, doubleanimation

i am creating a small game in uwp and i got stack on something
i wanted so that when a button s clicked, a grid rises to the top from the bottom
with the help of double animation, but i got an error
this is my code

```
DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
    Storyboard myStoryboard = new Storyboard();
    private void levelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        animation.From = 1.0;
        animation.To = 0.0;
        animation.Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 20));
        animation.AutoReverse = true;
        animation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        myStoryboard.Children.Add(animation);
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(animation, "levelTab");
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new 
        PropertyPath(levelTab.Margin.TopProperty));
        myStoryboard.Begin(this);

    }
```

the propertypath code was the problem, i got an error that said thicness does not contain any property like "TopProperty", then when i changed the "TopProperty"to just Top, i got an error that "cant convert from double to string"
and then when i change the "top" to "top.toString()" i get another error

lastly, i got another error on the last line ("myStoryboard.Begin(this)")
which was "no overload for begin takes 1 argument"
i will be gratefull for anyone that can help me achieve what i want to do with any method(apart from using a timer or dispatcher time because i think they take too much system resources and makes the application slow)

P.S, i also tried a using the do-while iteration, but i only got the output after the iteration was done, even when i added a code to sleep the thread...i want the user to see when the grid is going up..thnx in advance

Comment: You cannot animate the margin because it's not a dependency property. Try translate x/y.

Comment: @Jessica that's incorrect, it's just matter of thickness. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542657/how-to-animate-margin-property-in-wpf) of animating margin along with some other methods to accomplish the same including translate. :)

Comment: @ChrisW. note this is UWP though. The value gets changed but won't be animated.

Comment: @Jessica, aaaah touché I forgot UWP was without thickness animation. +1 and a beer owed for sure! However, it's still a value that can be interacted with a keyframe animation (regardless of type) wherein the value can be stepped++ from 0 to the desired end value via `KeyTime` creating the animation. Just as what say something like a Double animation does for you when it fills in the blanks from the start and finish value. So I'll still err on the side of caution and reaffirm it's *incorrect* that it *cannot* be done. Not recommended in lieu of Translate, but is definitely do-able. Cheers :)

Comment: thns jessica, translation works perfectly